# Por que obtenho "Segmentation Fault", mas se eu removo o * na chamada de printf isso não acontece?

Tags: c

```
int alloc(int * pointer, int num){
    scanf("%d", &num);
    pointer = (int *) malloc(num*sizeof(int));
    return(*pointer);
}

int main(){
    int *pointer;
    int num;
    alloc(pointer, num);
    printf("%d", *pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please speak portuguese.

Comment: Quando está a fazer o alloc, dá return no *pointer, logo penso que no printf não precisa do *

Comment: O que tentou fazer com esse código? Na função `alloc` você passa um parâmetro `num` que é lido do usuário e só é utilizado para definir o tamanho de memória alocada em `pointer`. No `printf` você tenta exibir o valor no ponteiro, que foi alocado mas sem nenhum valor atribuído. Qual seria o resultado esperado?

Comment: @IanMoone O retorno da função nesse caso é indiferente dado que na chamada de `alloc` o retorno é ignorado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss na verdade era so uma atividade vou te passar a questão:
Implemente uma função que aloque dinamicamente um vetor
de inteiros. Essa função deverá receber como parâmetro um
inteiro representando o tamanho do vetor, e retornar um
ponteiro representando o vetor alocado.

eu acho que eu entendi a questão errada a proposito, e eu queria printar o endereço do ponteiro somente

Comment: @MauryDeveloper eu pensava que o forum era so em ingles, desculpe

Comment: Note que da maneira como construiu sua função alloc você estará colocando o endereço da área de memória alocada com malloc na pilha de parâmetros da função e não na variável definida em sua main.

Comment: Se quiser saber mais detalhes veja a resposta bastante didática e explicativa de Jefferson Quesado em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/403341/ponteiro-vindo-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-n%c3%a3o-imprime