# Ponteiro vindo de uma função não imprime

Tags: c

Então pessoal, ganhei um dever de casa aqui, comecei ponteiros agora e não consegui compreender muito bem, já tentei de várias maneiras passar o valor de "i" para a função main e imprimí-lo, porém de nenhum jeito consegui, atualmente o código está assim e não imprime a linha que tenta imprimir o ponteiro. Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como fazer o que quero? Agradeço desde já!

```
int conferir(int vetor[], int numero, int *p)
{
    int i=0, flag=0;
    for(i = 0;i < 5; i++){
        if(numero == vetor[i]){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    p = &i;
    return flag;
}

int main()
{
    int v[5], num=0;
    int *p;

    printf("Digite o número para ser conferido com o vetor:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if(conferir(v,num,p) == 1){
        printf("Esse número existe no vetor");
        printf(" e está na posição %d\n", *p);
        }
    else{
        printf("Esse número não existe no vetor.\n");
        }
}
```

Os números do vetor estão sendo gerados aleatóriamente em outra função, o programa roda até a linha que tenta imprimir a posição do número no vetor.

edit:não postei muitas perguntas ainda, to aprendendo o jeito certo de postar, já me desculpo por qualquer erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que aconteceu aqui: quando você passa para a função `conferir` a variável `p`, ele faz exatamente isso: o valor de `p`. Porém, qualquer mudança que afete o valor de `p` dentro da função não interfere no mundo fora da função. Em compensação, você alterar um valor **apontado por `p`** é bem diferente.

Vamos fazer um teste de mesa? Vou "rodar" o programa e acompanhar os seus estados internos, como seria rodado após ser compilado pelo GCC ou coisa equivalente. Considerando aqui inteiros e ponteiros com 1 bytes por questão de simplicidade

Primeiro, iniciamos o programa. Temos a seguinte stack:

```
00: $$1    # v,v[0]
01: $$2    # v[0]
02: $$3    # v[1]
03: $$4    # v[1]
04: $$5    # v[2]
05: $$6    # v[2]
06: $$7    # v[3]
07: $$8    # v[3]
08: $$9    # v[4]
09: $$A    # v[4]
0A: $$B    # num
0B: $$C    # num
0C: $$D    # p
0D: $$E    # p
```

Tudo com lixo na memória (porque não foram inicializados). Então vamos até o `scanf(&num)`. Vamos supor que a pessoa entrou com `1`:

```
00: $$1    # *v,v[0]
01: $$2    # v[0]
02: $$3    # v[1]
03: $$4    # v[1]
04: $$5    # v[2]
05: $$6    # v[2]
06: $$7    # v[3]
07: $$8    # v[3]
08: $$9    # v[4]
09: $$A    # v[4]
0A:   1    # num
0B:   0    # num
0C: $$D    # p
0D: $$E    # p
```

Então chamamos a função `conferir`. Nesse caso, o compilador entende que devemos copiar os *valores* das variáveis e indicar para a função que eles estão no seu alcance. Veríamos globalmente assim a memória:

```
00: $$1    # v,v[0]
01: $$2    # v[0]
02: $$3    # v[1]
03: $$4    # v[1]
04: $$5    # v[2]
05: $$6    # v[2]
06: $$7    # v[3]
07: $$8    # v[3]
08: $$9    # v[4]
09: $$A    # v[4]
0A:   1    # num
0B:   0    # num
0C: $$D    # p
0D: $$E    # p
0E: $$D    # (conferir) p
0F: $$E    # (conferir) p
10:   1    # (conferir) numero
11:   0    # (conferir) numero
12:  &0G   # (conferir) vetor
13:  &0G   # (conferir) vetor
14:   0    # (conferir) i
15:   0    # (conferir) i
16:   0    # (conferir) flag
17:   0    # (conferir) flag
```

> Note que estou usando a notação "`&0G`" para indicar que é um apontamento para a "posição de memória" "0" no escopo "global", para não confundir com variáveis inteiras nem com o "posicionamento local", mostrado a seguir

Localmente, veríamos algo assim:

```
-6: $$D    # p
-5: $$E    # p
-4:   1    # numero
-3:   0    # numero
-2:  &0G   # vetor
-1:  &0G   # vetor
00:   0    # i
01:   0    # i
02:   0    # flag
03:   0    # flag
```

Ao fazer `p = &i`, isso é o que acontece:

```
-6:  &14G  # p
-5:  &14G  # p
-4:   1    # numero
-3:   0    # numero
-2:  &0G   # vetor
-1:  &0G   # vetor
00:   5    # i
01:   0    # i
02: $$X    # flag
03: $$Y    # flag
```

Na visão global:

```
00: $$1    # v,v[0]
01: $$2    # v[0]
02: $$3    # v[1]
03: $$4    # v[1]
04: $$5    # v[2]
05: $$6    # v[2]
06: $$7    # v[3]
07: $$8    # v[3]
08: $$9    # v[4]
09: $$A    # v[4]
0A:   1    # num
0B:   0    # num
0C: $$D    # p
0D: $$E    # p
0E:  &14G  # (conferir) p
0F:  &14G  # (conferir) p
10:   1    # (conferir) numero
11:   0    # (conferir) numero
12:  &0G   # (conferir) vetor
13:  &0G   # (conferir) vetor
14:   5    # (conferir) i
15:   0    # (conferir) i
16: $$X    # (conferir) flag
17: $$Y    # (conferir) flag
```

Note que o valor de memória nas posições `0C` e `0D` *não sofreram alteração*. Quando a chamada retornar, "virtualmente" perdemos a pilha da função, ficando apenas com isso:

```
00: $$1    # v,v[0]
01: $$2    # v[0]
02: $$3    # v[1]
03: $$4    # v[1]
04: $$5    # v[2]
05: $$6    # v[2]
06: $$7    # v[3]
07: $$8    # v[3]
08: $$9    # v[4]
09: $$A    # v[4]
0A:   1    # num
0B:   0    # num
0C: $$D    # p
0D: $$E    # p
```

Que é exatamente o estado anterior. Mas, como resolver isso? O comportamento desejado seria, de algum jeito, tornar "global" o valor de `i` sem usar um `return`.

Para tal, a primeira coisa que se deve prestar atenção é que não desejamos alterar o valor de `p` **dentro** da função, mas sim o valor **apontado** por `p`. Isso significa que fazer `p = XXX;` é um pecado, pois estaria alterando o valor de `p`. Para alterar o valor apontado por `p`, precisamos fazer `*p = XXX;`. [Leia mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247773/64969).

A outra coisa que precisamos tomar cuidado é que precisamos de uma região de memória *adequada* para esse fim. E um lixo na variável de ponteiro não vai nos ajudar com isso. Portanto, temos duas opções:

- apontar para uma variável local conhecida (deveria ser criada nesse momento)
- criar dinamicamente um espaço de memória para receber esse valor

A segunda abordagem não vou nem explorar aqui, apenas a citei para que você possa estudar mais depois. No caso da primeira, minha sugestão é:

- ter uma variável qualquer inteira na `main` (vamos chamá-la de `qualquer`)
- não ter variáveis do tipo ponteiro na `main`
- passar para a função `conferir` o endereço da variável `qualquer`

Ficaria assim o trecho modificado:

```c
int conferir(int vetor[], int numero, int *p)
{
    int i=0, flag=0;
    for(i = 0;i < 5; i++){
        if(numero == vetor[i]){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    *p = i;
    return flag;
}

int main()
{
    int v[5], num=0;
    int qualquer;

    printf("Digite o número para ser conferido com o vetor:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if(conferir(v,num,&qualquer) == 1){
...
```

Rodando o teste de mesa:

```
00: $$1    # v,v[0]
01: $$2    # v[0]
02: $$3    # v[1]
03: $$4    # v[1]
04: $$5    # v[2]
05: $$6    # v[2]
06: $$7    # v[3]
07: $$8    # v[3]
08: $$9    # v[4]
09: $$A    # v[4]
0A: $$B    # num
0B: $$C    # num
0C: $$D    # qualquer
0D: $$E    # qualquer
```

Tudo com lixo na memória (porque não foram inicializados). Então vamos até o `scanf(&num)`. Vamos supor que a pessoa entrou com `1`:

```
00: $$1    # *v,v[0]
01: $$2    # v[0]
02: $$3    # v[1]
03: $$4    # v[1]
04: $$5    # v[2]
05: $$6    # v[2]
06: $$7    # v[3]
07: $$8    # v[3]
08: $$9    # v[4]
09: $$A    # v[4]
0A:   1    # num
0B:   0    # num
0C: $$D    # qualquer
0D: $$E    # qualquer
```

Então chamamos a função `conferir`. Nesse caso, o compilador entende que devemos copiar os *valores* das variáveis e indicar para a função que eles estão no seu alcance. Veríamos globalmente assim a memória:

```
00: $$1    # v,v[0]
01: $$2    # v[0]
02: $$3    # v[1]
03: $$4    # v[1]
04: $$5    # v[2]
05: $$6    # v[2]
06: $$7    # v[3]
07: $$8    # v[3]
08: $$9    # v[4]
09: $$A    # v[4]
0A:   1    # num
0B:   0    # num
0C: $$D    # qualquer
0D: $$E    # qualquer
0E:  &CG   # (conferir) p
0F:  &CG   # (conferir) p
10:   1    # (conferir) numero
11:   0    # (conferir) numero
12:  &0G   # (conferir) vetor
13:  &0G   # (conferir) vetor
14:   0    # (conferir) i
15:   0    # (conferir) i
16:   0    # (conferir) flag
17:   0    # (conferir) flag
```

> Note que estou usando a notação "`&0G`" para indicar que é um apontamento para a "posição de memória" "0" no escopo "global", para não confundir com variáveis inteiras nem com o "posicionamento local", mostrado a seguir

Localmente, veríamos algo assim:

```
-6:  &CG   # p
-5:  &CG   # p
-4:   1    # numero
-3:   0    # numero
-2:  &0G   # vetor
-1:  &0G   # vetor
00:   0    # i
01:   0    # i
02:   0    # flag
03:   0    # flag
```

Ao fazer `*p = i`, isso é o que acontece:

```
-6:  &CG   # p
-5:  &CG   # p
-4:   1    # numero
-3:   0    # numero
-2:  &0G   # vetor
-1:  &0G   # vetor
00:   5    # i
01:   0    # i
02: $$X    # flag
03: $$Y    # flag
```

Na visão global:

```
00: $$1    # v,v[0]
01: $$2    # v[0]
02: $$3    # v[1]
03: $$4    # v[1]
04: $$5    # v[2]
05: $$6    # v[2]
06: $$7    # v[3]
07: $$8    # v[3]
08: $$9    # v[4]
09: $$A    # v[4]
0A:   1    # num
0B:   0    # num
0C:   5    # qualquer
0D:   0    # qualquer
0E:  &CG   # (conferir) p
0F:  &CG   # (conferir) p
10:   1    # (conferir) numero
11:   0    # (conferir) numero
12:  &0G   # (conferir) vetor
13:  &0G   # (conferir) vetor
14:   0    # (conferir) i
15:   0    # (conferir) i
16: $$X    # (conferir) flag
17: $$Y    # (conferir) flag
```

Ao retornar da função e "desempilhar" suas variáveis, temos:

```
00: $$1    # v,v[0]
01: $$2    # v[0]
02: $$3    # v[1]
03: $$4    # v[1]
04: $$5    # v[2]
05: $$6    # v[2]
06: $$7    # v[3]
07: $$8    # v[3]
08: $$9    # v[4]
09: $$A    # v[4]
0A:   1    # num
0B:   0    # num
0C:   5    # qualquer
0D:   0    # qualquer
```

Com o devido efeito colateral, que era alterar o valor da variável `qualquer`.

Comment: Nossa, esperava uma solução, mas não tão bem elaborada e didática, muito obrigado pela resposta e pela atenção!

Comment: @placementw, minha resposta está mais didática do que estritamente correta. Esperando uma resposta tecnicamente perfeita do Maniero